# Checkbox not printing after restoring values from localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

We have some checkboxes in our code when selecting checkbox and executing window.print(), checked boxes is displayed. But when we reset items and Restore again and after that if we execute window.print() selected checkboxes are not displayed.

## Here is code for storing checkbox into localstorage

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    let id = $(this).attr('id');
  var checkbox = document.getElementById(id);
    localStorage.setItem(id, checkbox.checked);
  });
```

## Get checkbox values from localstorage

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    let id=$(this).attr('id');
  var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(id));
    document.getElementById(id).checked = checked;
    
  });
```

[image: After clicking print without restoring values from localstorage]

[image: After restoring values from localstorage and clicking print]

Comment: Can you share the code. Because there is no error in storing and accessing the localstorage values.

Comment: Yes, Iam getting error after executing window.print(). Here i am not able to display selected checkbox. Clicking print button will be saved as pdf format

Comment: Share some code so I can get an idea what exactly the issue is.

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code you have provided. Could you provide more of the code so we can see the context?